# how to master in Windows administration

Tags: windows, administrator

what is, in your opinion, best way to become real Windows, advanced administrator?
Of course it's possible to obtain MS Certificates, but they're rather very expensive.

Almost two years of everyday working on Linux machine, teach me, that it's very important to read system logs. Anyway, I assume that it's enough - I think that you must be familiar with almost any hive in you registry and each trick in Windows CMD and VBS- although it's high time for PowerShell, still on many maschines, you have only an opprotunity of using CMD by default (and their owners are reluctant to install anything else).

How I can accomplish this task? Which groups follows (*superUser - it' obligatory*), which articles read?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to learn anything is to dive in and look for incoming solutions. Answering posts on StackExchange is also a good learning point as when answering you should recheck your skills and sometime find something new.

If you up for some system administration look for example at [critical security controls](http://www.sans.org/critical-security-controls/) or [everythingsysadmin](http://everythingsysadmin.com/the-test.html) and try to follow this rules to build a good network. If you think you misunderstand something - learn about that.

You know, any Certificates are just plain paper. Only knowledge and experience counts. I'm not a super-duper Windows admin yet as I tend to work on FreeBSD but I can assure you that everything you would learn about IP networks, WWW, e-mail should work exactly the same way on any OS.